# Can you use String.fromCodePoint just like String.fromCharCode

Tags: javascript, input

I'm still learning JavaScript and practicing with getting input from a keyboard.  I just learned about `String.fromCodePoint` and it seems (to me) to pick up everything that `String.fromCharCode` does.

Is `String.fromCodePoint` supported widespread by browsers and devices and if so, does it make `String.fromCharCode` obsolete, or is there a reason you would use `String.fromCharCode` instead sometimes?

Comment: take a look at for browser compatibility http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#String.fromCodePoint

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`fromCharCode` is not obsolete yet, but it would be if it would be supported by all Browsers. However `fromCharCode` is about [twice as fast](https://jsperf.com/fromcharcode-vs-fromcodepoint/6) as `fromCodePoint`

- [String.fromCodePoint()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint)
  Not supported by Internet Explorer and Safari
- [String.fromCharCode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode)
  Supported since for ever, double as fast
- The difference:

  > Although most common Unicode values can be represented with one 16-bit number (as expected early on during JavaScript standardization) and fromCharCode() can be used to return a single character for the most common values (i.e., UCS-2 values which are the subset of UTF-16 with the most common characters), in order to deal with ALL legal Unicode values (up to 21 bits), fromCharCode() alone is inadequate. Since the higher code point characters use two (lower value) "surrogate" numbers to form a single character, String.fromCodePoint() (part of the ES6 draft) can be used to return such a pair and thus adequately represent these higher valued characters.

Comment: I didn't realize fromCharCode would be that much faster... thanks for sharing that speed test link.  For now I'll stick with fromCharCode for just basic keyboard input.

Comment: Please note that the difference in performance is now negligible -- make sure to run the test on your own before making a decision.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović where can an updated source for this information be found? The link in the answer gives me code 500.

Comment: This answer is outdated since they are now widely supported by almost every browsers
https://caniuse.com/?search=fromcharcode
https://caniuse.com/?search=fromcodepoint

Answer (score 6):

**String.fromCharCode** is supported on all browsers:
[image]

**String.fromCodePoint** has limited browser support:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

`String.fromCodePoint` is not widely supported, in fact it's not supported at all in Internet Explorer and Safari, and only in Chrome 41 and up, and Firefox 29 and up.

This doesn't mean it's obsolete, it means it's a new method, only first defined in ES2015.
It also means that browser support will get better in time, as browsers implement all the new features in the 6th edition of ECMAScript.

For now, it's not very suitable for production use if you need to support all current browsers, but there is a polyfill available on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint) if you really need to have this method available in all browsers.