# How to insert emoticons chars into JS script

Tags: javascript, unicode

How can I use emoticon chars in JS :

http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html#1f600

I tried with:

```
var emoji = String.fromCharCode(0x1F621);
var emoji = '\u1F600';
```

I also tried to copy/paste them into phpStorm IDE and into sublime text : that gave me a squared missing char.

I just need to have a `console.log('')` inside my JS !

Comment: That just means that the font used in your IDE does not support this particular emoji.

Comment: I tried with DW, SublimeText, PhpSortm, Notepad++
If you know an IDE that supports them, please let me know

Comment: Just try setting your IDE to a font that you have installed and that can display them. Of course another possibility is that your OS doesn't support copy-pasting them.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
var emoji = String.fromCodePoint(0x1F621)
```

Result:

```
""
```

Be careful about [limited browser support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34680983/6730571), though, as `String.fromCodePoint()` is part of the ES2015 standard. See Mozilla's [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint#Polyfill) if needed.

The [language spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.3.2) explains why `fromCharCode` does not work:

> [the argument is] converted to a character by applying the operation `ToUint16` and regarding the resulting 16-bit integer as the code unit value of a character.

and the emoji block is beyond the maximum value supported by unsigned 16-bit integers.

Comment: GREAT: but what about some older browsers ?

Comment: There's a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint#Polyfill)

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```js
// emoji code from w3schools //
//***************************//
  var code = {
    ok: "9989",     hurrcane : "128165",  Up : "11014",    Down : "11015",    Hashtag : "35",    Clock : "9200", P : "127359",    Okay : "10004",    NotOkay : "10006"
  }
// emoji in javascript       //
//***************************//
  function emoji(ecode)
  {
    return String.fromCodePoint(ecode);
  }
  console.log(emoji(code.Clock)+emoji(code.Okay))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).